# Why javac task does not creates classes

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant task that contains javac task inside. It reports about error in one of the classes, but the build doesn't fail, because it has failonerror="false". I suppose to see class files in the end of build, but I don't see it. Can anybody tell me why?

Properties used:

```
checkout.path=work/workingcopy
classpath.path=work/build/classes
log.file=work/log.txt
```

Ant code:

```
<record name="${log.file}" action="start"/>     
<javac destdir="${classpath.path}" srcdir="${checkout.path}/src"
        debug="true" failonerror="false">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="webinf.lib"/>
        <path refid="tomcat.lib"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
<record name="${log.file}" action="stop"/>
```

Log file:

```
[javac] Compiling 169 source files to C:\work\build\classes
[javac] C:\work\workingcopy\src\com\mycompany\exception\handlerException\CustomExceptionHandler.java:25: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class RequestContextImpl
[javac] location: package org.primefaces.context
[javac] import org.primefaces.context.RequestContextImpl;
[javac]                              ^
[javac] C:\work\workingcopy\src\com\mycompany\exception\handlerException\CustomExceptionHandler.java:103: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class RequestContextImpl
[javac] location: class com.mycompany.exception.handlerException.CustomExceptionHandler
[javac]             new RequestContextImpl(ec);
[javac]                 ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 2 errors
[javac] Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failonerror option is for Ant not for `javac`. So if `failonerror=false` then Ant will continue your task even `javac` returns an error.

From the docs:

*failonerror* Indicates whether compilation errors will fail the build; defaults to true.

The **build** is Ant's build process not javac's !

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know how to cause the compiler, to compile java files. The log shows that there are 169 source files and there are errors only in one. Why there are no class files for other 168?

Comment: javac won´t create any .class file while there are errors. It makes no sense to have partial compiled classes, your program won`t run !

Comment: Anyway, seems org.primefaces.context.RequestContextImpl is not on your classpath.

Comment: You are right, but it is OK. My task is to create script that makes daily builds. If there are errors, it should check in list of critical files. If this class is critical it fails, else uses old version of the class. I thought that javac compiles sources without errors, even if there are an error in other sources, but you tell me  that it is wrong. Is any option to override this behaivour exists?

Comment: AFAIK there is no option in Sun's javac. There are other Java compiler (jikes,etc) that maybe allow this (i doubt). Anyway you can take the error output of compilation to identify sources with errors and handle them in any specific manner.

Comment: You manage daily builds and wants to use old classes when new ones fails. Sounds a little bit scary to me ...

Comment: It sounded strange to me too, when I've first hear about it. The explanation was, that we have a huge project, so QA section should be able to test part A, even if B still doesn't work. BTW, I still think that there is some way to compile only files without errors, because Eclipse does it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Eclipse Java Compiler** (EJC) instead of standard Oracle javac. One of ECJ advantages over javac is that it is permissible of errors, it tries to compile as much as possible and keeps already generated class files. With javac it is everything or nothing.

EJC was developed for use in IDE, for highly interactive work where partial compilation is a must, but it can also be used as CLI or Maven plugin. Plexus guys provide EJC as a handy Maven dependency.

For example configuration of ECJ in Maven, a partial compilation, check my answer to this question:
[Maven: partial compilation before code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665815/maven-partial-compilation-before-code-generation/20692364#20692364)

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. And that is soluion I've found on the Web

*This depends on the compiler that you are actually using.  If you're using
javac 1.3, this is what Sun does by design.  (see
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/tools-changes.html for more
information, specifically the last paragraph of the first bullet.)
Try using an older compiler or using the jikes compiler from IBM.  Both
javac 1.2.2 and jikes 1.13 will produce output for classes that do compile,
even if another file in the fileset doesn't.
Jay*

Best regards,
Michael