# Maven: partial compilation before code generation

Tags: java, maven

**tl;dr-edition:** I have a compilation I know that will fail, but want the subset of classes that are still compilable in my `target/classes` folder after compilation. I have configured `<failOnError>false</failOnError>`, but no classes are generated, not even a dummy class that is independent of any other classes except `Object`. Is there some configuration to achieve this?

---

I have a maven-powered project whose workflow consists of basically the following (relevant) goals:

- `...`
- `init-compile`

  The code generator (below) uses a config that is reflection-based, so, in a first pass, I want to try compile as much of the project as possible so that no ClassNotFoundExceptions are thrown there. This compilation is configured with `<failOnError>false</failOnError>` so that the build continues.

  Unfortunately (you could call it a design flaw), the config is used both for code generation (specifying the OWL file and namespace to package mappings) and at runtime, so it also contains other elements that are not needed for the code generator, but are still read and therefore needed on the classpath to succeed.
- `generate-model`

  In this step, some model classes are generated from an OWL-Ontology, creating the code that makes the rest of the project completely compileable.
- `default-compile`

  Now, the rest of the classes should be compiled, obviously
- `save-model`

  Now, the instances from the ontology are read and serialized to a file for runtime
- `...`

Side note: both generate and save model use `maven-exec-plugin`, but I sincerely don't think that matters at all.

**Question:**

When I run my build with `mvn -e -U clean package source:jar javadoc:jar install:install`, it fails during the `generate-model` goal with the errors I'm trying to avoid. `target/classes` is empty, so it seems that the compiler doesn't spit out the subset of classes it could/should have been able to process. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have two workarounds in mind which I both don't like:

- Editing the config file "AST" before parsing it into Java-Objects, so that only the part relevant for the code generator is parsed (needs tweaking of code that I have access to but should be considered immutable by my project);
- and to configure the `init-compile` goal to only include the needed classes (too inflexible, because the POM should/could be a template for future applications using the same model).

If you can imagine another way to work around my problem that you can see from my description, I would be glad to hear them, too!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - does your build not work when you move your generate-model goal to the generate-sources phase?

Comment: The config is provided on the classpath, where it is also found at runtime of the application, forgot to say that, so generate-model (and init-compile before that) are executed during process-resources. But as stated above, the real problem is more or less that I need an initial, incomplete compile that provides classes referenced in the config. I guess I will end up with the first workaround, but I'm still interested in how to achieve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me recapitulate your problem to be sure I've grasped it properly.

- You have a set of classes whose function, in their compiled form, is
  to configure both the code generator and the runtime.  (A subset of
  these are relevant to the code generator, but generation will fail
  unless the complete configuration is present.  So we can treat it as
  though the entire configuration were necessary.)
- You then have a set of classes which will be generated as source
  code.  These have a generation-time, perhaps a compile-time, and a
  run-time dependency upon the configuration classes.
- Finally you have some other code which has a compile-time dependency
  upon the generated classes, and a runtime dependency upon both the
  generated classes and the configuration classes.
- However, your configuration classes don't have any compile-time dependencies upon the generated classes nor upon the other code.  You don't explicitly say this, but I'm assuming it, otherwise you've got a circular dependency problem.

**Here's my suggestion:** Divide the project into a multi-module ("reactor") project.  Your current project will be a module of the reactor project.  Create a new module called "config" or similar and move your config classes into it.  Have the main module depend upon it.

If you don't like multi-module projects, you could achieve the same thing by declaring an extra execution of the compile plugin, bound to the generate-sources phase.  (You don't say, but I assume you're doing the code generation in this phase.  If you declare the compile plugin before the code generator plugin within the POM, Maven will execute them in the same order.)  You would use the "include" filter of the compile plugin to compile only the config classes.  For this, you would need to have the config classes in a separate package from all the rest, which is good practice anyway.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Splitting the project is theoretically an option, but I think a little overkill for my usecase (which is performance testing: we have individual projects for test cases, so doubling the number of projects is cumbersome). Just to let you know, I went with a variant of workaround 1, where I read the whole config, but only parse a subtree of it as java objects ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is one highly convenient solution - use **Eclipse Java Compiler (EJC)** instead of standard Oracle javac! One of ECJ advantages over javac is that it is permissible of errors, it tries to compile as much as possible and keeps already generated *class* files. EJC was developed for use in IDE, for highly interactive work where partial compilation is a must, but it can also be used as CLI or Maven plugin. Plexus guys provide EJC as a handy Maven dependency.

Compilers are pluggable in Maven. You can have multiple compilation (compilation executions) defined in one POM and you can use different compilers for each giving the developer broad range of options.

Example POM code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-compilation</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                <!-- IMPORTANT. Select EJC as compiler instead of javac -->
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                <!-- IMPORTANT. When ECJ is used errors are reported 
                only as warnings, it continues in compilation, 
                try to compile as much as possible, keeps already 
                generated classes in target/classes -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <!-- in the end recompile everything with standard javac.
                 This time no compilation errors are expected or tolerated. -->
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

<!-- generate sources. This plugin executes in facet BETWEEN the compilations due to 
    'generate-sources' phase binding and relative position in POM -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
    <artifactId>xtext-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-the-stuff</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Credits to Gabriel Axel for his article http://www.gabiaxel.com/2011/10/replacing-javac-with-eclipse-compiler.html

This approach can solve some tricky "*source* to *generated source* to *source*" circular dependencies, potentially unsolvable by splitting into separate modules.

Also, I wanted to integrate source generation in the most transparent way. Having to reshuffle the code based on dependencies on generated sources would definitively break it. I want to group my code based on logical design not because of technicalities.

If you code generator happens to xtext, like in my case, and you use xtext-maven-plugin, let's say freshly released 2.5.0, you don't have to configure nothing like in the example above, the plugin does exactly that under the hood.