# Compile and execute a single file to generate code before compiling all the code together

Tags: maven

A maven project with some generated files:

```
my.package.R // generated from resources
my.package.ClassThatGeneratesRFromResources
my.package.AClassThatUsesR
my.package.AnotherClassThatUsesR
my.package.YetAnotherClassThatUsesR
```

When building, I would like to compile ClassThatGeneratesRFromResources, execute it (thus generating the R.java class) and then compile everything else together.

I can make this work with modules, a reactor, and isolating ClassThatGeneratesRFromResources in its own little module. However, I wonder why my ugly, clunky solution is not working. Here is my current POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>
                        generate-r-file-creator
                    </id>
                    <configuration>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <includes>
                          <include>my/package/ClassThatGeneratesRFromResources.java</include>
                       </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-r-files</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>my.package.ClassThatGeneratesRFromResources</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                           <argument>${basedir}</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>        
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The result is that the initial compiler run fails, and then the code-generation run fails too (because ClassThatGeneratesRFromResources has not been compiled). **Why is my compiler plugin not being triggered**? How can I fix this (other than [going modular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665815/maven-partial-compilation-before-code-generation))?

Comment: Still curious about the Right Way to Do It (tm)... but for the time being, I have solved the issue by writing it up in an ant target which is called via antrun plugin